# How can I deserializing JSON while returns different type?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I post some data to the remote server. When the data run succeeded, it returns:

```
{"access_token":"sd234sd234sdf324","expires_in":7200}
```

When it failed, it returns:

```
{"errcode":40013,"errmsg":"invalid appid"}
```

Here is my code:

```
    HttpClient HC = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage HRM = await HC.PostAsync("https://www.microsoft/callback/aaa/), null);
    string Content = await HRM.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Models.SuccessModel SM=(Models.SuccessModel)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Content, typeof(Models.SuccessModel));
```

The last part for converting JSON to the class, I used the SuccessModel yet but if returns the failed JSON it will throw an error which Type is wrong.

I know what the error is. But how can I deal with this?

I want to get whether it is succeeded or failed and get the value of it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another model for error as follows:

```
public class ErrorModel
{
   public string errcode {get;set;}
   public string errmsg {get;set;}
}
```

Then do as follows:

```
string response = await HRM.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (response.Contains("access_token", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Models.SuccessModel successModel =(Models.SuccessModel)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(response, typeof(Models.SuccessModel));
} else
{
    ErrorModel erroModel = (Models.ErrorModel)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(response,typeof(Models.ErrorModel));
}
```

Comment: Well, that's great and easy.

Answer (score 1):

However, you can work this way

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string access_token { get; set;}
    public long expires_in { get; set;}
    public int errcode { get; set;}
    public string errmsg { get; set;}
}
```

So just get the response and check errcode when use it, no need to check when Deserialize